# Python access attributes of an enclosing class (not parent)

Tags: python, django, class

I have a simple problem, I'm developing something for which I need to have some classes accessing some common variables like that:

```
somevar="foo"

class A(SomeParent):
  def eval_class(self):
     global somevar
     return somevar

def index(request,input_somevar):
  global somevar
  somevar=input_somevar
  return HttpResponse(A().eval_class())
```

Problem: That code runs on django so, every request the code will be still running and the somevar will reiceve a new value. If requests happen to overlap I'll enp up having values of somevar for one request which are set by another request.

Solution? What came to my mind was to use instances of a single class.

```
Class Parent:
  somevar=None
  def set_somevar(self,somevar):
    self.somevar=somevar

  class A(SomeParent): #Note: the parent of this class is NOT "Parent".
    def eval_class(self):
      #Here I would like to retrieve somehow "somevar"
      return somevar

def index(request,input_somevar):
  p=Parent()
  p.set_somevar(input_somevar)
  return HttpResponse(p.A().eval_class())
```

**NOTE:** I cannot pass variables to the classes, they have to be able to access to the "enclosing but not parent class" as they are sympy's Function classes which need to be passed to the sympy interpreter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you say that different threads of your Django app have an access conflict: while one of them is reading the value of `somevar`, another is modifying it.

So you seem to be solving a wrong problem. Really you need to design your application in a way that access conflicts do not happen.

An ideal solution would be having no shared state at all. Use [`threading.local`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local) to store data accessible to only one (current) thread. You will have to sort out affinity issues, though: if one request goes to this thread and the next request of the same client, minutes later, goes to another thread, it will not see the data set by the previous request.

Another solution would be using a database to serialize the changes. Take SQLite, it's almost weightless and supports transactions. One change locks the `somevar` record for update, and another transaction that would change it will fail. You'll have to sort this out, again, in a meaningful manner.

It would help if you described the bigger problem you're solving.

Comment: Well basically the problem is more complicated. I receive some input, I call a library which executes some heavy map/reduce operations on a db. This operation takes several seconds. So if in the meanwhile I receive some other input the map/reduce process will start reading the new input (which have nothing to do with the previous one). Should I be redesigning part of my code to use threading.local? docs are quite obscure..

Comment: great, that solved my problem, incapsulating the function in a thread and then using local worked like a charm without changing too much code. you just made my day ;)

Answer (score 0):

with `set_somvevar()` you are setting the value of the attribute of the instance `p`, while the `somevar` global remains unchanged. Thus, `p.A().eval_class()` will always return `None` (the original value).

edit:
with the global `somevar` defined as a class attribute instead of an instance attribute, setting this attribute will not solve your problem: you still get the latest set value of this class attribute, assuming you meant
with `eval_class` to return `P().somevar`.

What about making the Parent-instance a variable to the A-init function?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, somevar):
        self.somevar = somevar

    class A(SomeParent):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            SomeParent.__init__(self)
            self.parent = parent

        def eval_class(self):
            return self.parent.somevar

def index(request,input_somevar):
  p = Parent(input_somevar)
  return HttpResponse(p.A(p).eval_class())
```

Comment: In the bottom code snippet, somevar is a class attribute, so self.somevar = somevar will indeed modify the attribute on the class, not just the instance. Those modifications will persist across requests, which is usually not a good thing for arguments to views.

Comment: That's true but doesn't help me much. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass input_somevar to the classes that need it?

```
class A(SomeParent):
    def eval_class(self, somevar):
        return somevar

def index(request,input_somevar):
    return HttpResponse(A().eval_class(input_somevar))
```

If your view calls other classes, pass it to those too if they need it.

Comment: I can't. In the specific it's a class of Sympy defining a special math function which cannot be "summoned" except by sympy itself in the process of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in java, nested classes are not linked to instances of the outer class. It just changes the namespace in which the class is available. That means `p.a` is the same thing as `Parent.A`.

As Brian said, the simplest thing to do might be to just pass the variables you need from your view.